# While creating a table in my SQl with with two columns. One with char data type and other with int data type. I am getting issue

Tags: mysql, etl

Hi I am new to ETL testing. I wanted to create a table Emp in my Sql,and load some data as per the insert satement below. But I am getting the following error while creating table.

The query used is shown below:

```
Create table Emp (Group char(1),Sequence integer);
insert into Emp values ('A','1'),('A','2'),('A','3'),('A',5),('A','6'),('A','8'),('A','9'),('B','11'),('C','1'),('C','2'),('C','3');
```

So, on using the above create statement. It shows errror as:

```
Create table Emp (Group char(1),Sequence integer)
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group char(1),Sequence integer)' at line 1   0.047 sec

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP` is a SQL keyword.

Comment: Specifically, it's a *reserved* keyword